# Como adicionar uma coluna com link no GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, gridview

Tenho o seguinte código que gera minha GridView:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AlteracoesContrato alteracoes = new AlteracoesContrato(movimentacaoId);
                grdListaAlteracoes.DataSource = alteracoes.ListaResumidaAlteracoes;
                if (alteracoes.ListaResumidaAlteracoes.Count > 0)
                {
                    lblAviso.Visible = false;
                    BoundField linkColumnBoundField = new BoundField();
                    linkColumnBoundField.HeaderText = "Visualizar";
                    grdListaAlteracoes.Columns.Add(linkColumnBoundField);

                    grdListaAlteracoes.DataBind();
                }
                else
                    lblAviso.Text = "Nenhuma alteração foi realizada nesse contrato.";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblAviso.Text = "Erro ao exibir alterações do contrato.";
                GravaLogErro(ex);
                ShowAlert(ERRO_RECUPERAR);
            }
        }
```

No trecho `grdListaAlteracoes.Columns.Add(linkColumnBoundField);` eu adiciono uma coluna na grid, mas não sei como popular cada campo com o link que desejo.

Pensei em montar o HTML direto na lista inicial que monta a Grid, mas fiz um teste e ela não faz o encode do HTML e o texto é mostrado com as tags ao invés do link.

Como posso adicionar essa coluna com com os links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução: eu precisava criar um `HyperLinkedField` e não `BoundField`. Depois disso, apenas vinculei a coluna criada com o campo onde gerei os links no `DataSource`.

Segue o código com a solução:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AlteracoesContrato alteracoes = new AlteracoesContrato(movimentacaoId);
        grdListaAlteracoes.DataSource = alteracoes.ListaResumidaAlteracoes;
        if (alteracoes.ListaResumidaAlteracoes.Count > 0)
        {
            lblAviso.Visible = false;  
            //Adicionar como link os dados de Visulizar:
            HyperLinkField linkColumnBoundField = new HyperLinkField();
            linkColumnBoundField.HeaderText = "Visualizar";
            linkColumnBoundField.DataTextField = "Visualizar";
            grdListaAlteracoes.Columns.Add(linkColumnBoundField);

            grdListaAlteracoes.DataBind();
        }
        else
            lblAviso.Text = "Nenhuma alteração foi realizada nesse contrato.";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblAviso.Text = "Erro ao exibir alterações do contrato.";
        GravaLogErro(ex);
        ShowAlert(ERRO_RECUPERAR);
    }
}
```

Como eu criei um novo campo no `DataSource` para gerar os links do `GridView`, precisei ocultar a coluna que ficou duplicada (sem o link). Pra isso usei o evento `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void grdListaAlteracoes_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
}
```